# IOS after Update Xcode 11, Multiple methods named 'numberOfItemsInSection:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: objective-c

[After update the Xcode , I GOT THIS ISSUSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj88q.png)
1.After update the Xcode.
  "Multiple methods named 'numberOfItemsInSection:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes "
I am doing iOS Objective-C. What is Issues?

Comment: Please post code as actual text in your question. Why are you trying to call a UITableViewDataSource method on some unknown object out of an array or dictionary?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue on IOS 13 i had to update

```
NSInteger numberOfBeforeSection = [_update[@"oldModel"] numberOfItemsInSection:updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate.section];
```

to

```
NSInteger numberOfBeforeSection =[(UICollectionView *)_update[@"oldModel"]numberOfItemsInSection:updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate.section];
```

hope it helps

Comment: I have a problem like U but relate to an enum type. how to fix it